# airline reservation column

Tags: python, while-loop

My homework assignment asks me to create an airline reservation system and I've completed most of it. I am having a problem though with making sure the column labels are `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` . Every time I run the code, it always says that the letter is not one of the options even when I think it is. I am also wondering how to make the dictionary stay when the `def` is repeated.

My code is:

```py
col=input("Col (A-D): ")
#make sure col is correct letter
while col!="A" or col!="B" or col!="C" or col!="D":
    col=input("Invalid column. Please enter a column from A to D: ")
else:
    name=input("Enter a name for the reservation: ")
```

Comment: If you type `A`, then `col!="B" or col!="C" or col!="D"`... So it will ask you to enter again. And what dictionary are you talking about?

Comment: Let's say I choose column 'A', so the condition `col!="A"` is False and the condition `col!="B"` is True. So, what would you expect from the condition `col!="A" or col!="B"`?

Comment: If you input "A" then the condition `col!="B"` is `True` (and so are the checks for C and D) so you get `while False or True or True or True:` which... is `True`. Instead you want `And`. This trips EVERYONE up the first time.

Comment: @JNevill OP wants `not in`, rather than `And`

Comment: Another option: `while col not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):` Or maybe `while col < 'A' or col > 'D':`

Comment: @OneCricketeer 100%

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, the main problem is the loop condition, you are looping while col is diferent from a, b, c or d, the only way to break the loop is that col was a, b, c and d at the same time, that is impossible.

The second problem is the while else, is unnecesary, the while else in python is only for check if the loop end has not been caused by a breask instruction, just put that code after the loop.

```py
col=input("Col (A-D): ")
#make sure col is correct letter
while not (col == "A" or col == "B" or col == "C" or col == "D"):
    col=input("Invalid column. Please enter a column from A to D: ")
name=input("Enter a name for the reservation: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while statement as written will always be true because you are using "or" conditions.

```
while col!="A" or col!="B" or col!="C" or col!="D":
```

You would want to use "and" logical conditioning so that you present the error message when the entry is not equal to any of the columns.  Also, you wouldn't really have an "else" clause associated with a "while" statement.  I believe the following code snippet will give you what you want.

```
while col!="A" and col!="B" and col!="C" and col!="D":
    col=input("Invalid column. Please enter a column from A to D: ")

name=input("Enter a name for the reservation: ")
```

Give that a try.  Hope that helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `or` logical condition, which should be an `and` instead.

I took the liberty to refactor your code a bit:

```
while (col := input("Col (A-D): ")) not in ("A", "B", "C", "D"):
    print("Invalid column.")

name=input("Enter a name for the reservation: ")
```